# sql query to count total days between min and max date from same column

Tags: mysql, sql

table name - receipt

coupondate - varchar

```
coupondate    customer      
 02-04-2015     A         
 02-05-2015     A         
 02-06-2015     A         
 02-07-2015     A        
 02-08-2015     A       
 02-09-2015     A  

 05-04-2015     B         
 05-05-2015     B         
 05-06-2015     B         
 05-07-2015     B        
 05-08-2015     B       
 05-09-2015     B
```

I need to calculate count of total days between min and max coupondate.

**FOR EX -**

coupondate of customer A starts from 02-04-2015 and end on 02-09-2015..so total days difference is 153 days..

coupondate of customer B starts from 05-04-2015 and end on 05-09-2015..so total days difference is 153 days..

**Expected output**

```
customer     totaldiff
  A           153 days
  B           153 days
```

**below is my sql query**

```
 SELECT customer_name,        
           COUNT( coupondate ) AS totaldiff
    FROM receipt_entry
    GROUP BY customer_name
```

Comment: You want two columns in the result (customer and totaldiff), but you select 5 columns. Perhaps you should just select customer_name, MAX( coupondate ) - MIN( coupondate ) ?

Comment: yes i need only 2 column but the main output i need is totaldifference ...

Comment: totaldifference, independent of user, or per user?

Comment: total difference is based on per user or customer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_name,
  DATEDIFF(MAX(coupondate), MIN(coupondate)) AS totaldiff
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY customer_name
```

Edited according to your comment, in case `coupondate` is a `VARCHAR`.
**Verify your date format first**

```
SELECT customer_name,
  DATEDIFF(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(coupondate, '%d-%m-%Y')), 
           MIN(STR_TO_DATE(coupondate, '%d-%m-%Y'))) AS totaldiff
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY customer_name
```

Comment: your query return NULL on totaldiff column

Comment: Returns all null or only some as null? Do you have null values for couple date in your table?

Comment: strange behaviour indeed :-\

Comment: You need modify you code to convert them correctly before datadiff

Comment: @ankit ingle You're welcome. Consider to change the `coupondate` data type if possible, to avoid the type conversion inside the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you get your expected results.

If you know the dates you want:

```
SELECT customer_name, DATEDIFF(DAY, '02/04/2015', '5/9/2015') AS totaldiff
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY customer_name
```

If you need to get your values and don't know them, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT A.customer_name, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, (min(coupondate)), (max(coupondate))) AS totaldiff
FROM A.receipt_entry
GROUP BY A.customer_name
```

Edit: I missed the MySQL reference, sorry, the above was for SQL Server, here is the MySQL code:

```
SELECT customer_name, 
DATEDIFF(min(coupondate)), max(coupondate)) AS totaldiff
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY customer_name
```

Edit 2: Date formatting:

```
SELECT customer_name, 
DATEDIFF(min(STR_TO_DATE(coupondate,'%d,%m,%Y')), max(STR_TO_DATE(coupondate,'%d,%m,%Y'))) AS totaldiff
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY customer_name
```

Comment: the second query will not return correct per customer values. It will return the same diff for everyone.

Comment: your query returns error...#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: I adjusted the code to correct what Tim3880 pointed out, and the error was because I didn't realize it was MySQL, I removed the 'DAY, ' from the datediff function.